# Unable to start Tomcat 6 .exe on Windows7

Tags: java, tomcat6

Not able to start the tomcat6 server. In command window I run:

> c:...Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin>tomcat6.exe

It shows the following exceptions.

```
[warn]  The system cannot find the Registry key for service 'tomcat6'
[error] Load configuration failed
[error] The system cannot find the file specified.
[error] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 2 (Failed to load configuration)
[error] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am using java 1.6.0_30 64 bit, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The installation process obviously failed. Try to run it again. The user who runs the installation process needs permissions to write to the registry.

If that doesn't work you may start Tomcat from the batch file (`startup.bat`) in `c:...Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin`.

Comment: I also so tried by executing startup.bat but i did not find any use:
It is displaying as following:
D:\Users\Softwares\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin>startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE: "D:\Users\Softwares\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\Users\Softwares\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\Users\Softwares\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\temp"
Using JRE_HOME: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30"
Using CLASSPATH: "D:\Users\Softwares\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin\bootstrap.jar"

Comment: "i did not find any use" - what is that supposed to mean? What you posted looks quite correct but I'm sure you cut off a few lines.

Comment: By executing startup.bat I am not able to start the server, is there any other way to run the server.

Comment: How can you tell the server isn't started? Do you get errors on the console? What happens if you go to `localhost:8080` with your browser (8080 is the default Tomcat port)? Please note that you can run `startup.bat` only once before stopping the server again as you cannot start the server more than once on the same port. Run `shutdown.bat`, delete all files in `D:\Users\Softwares\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\logs`, run `startup.bat` and check the log files.

Comment: I tried with localhost:8080 in the browser after executing startup.bat, I did not find the tomcat home page.